# Funcion para navegar dentro de una misma pagina sin usar Scroll

Tags: javascript, aplicación-web

Imaginate que tengo una pagina que tiene las siguientes lineas en la parte de abajo o final  de la pagina, lo que nesecito es una funcion que al ejecutar muestre el contenido en la pantalla que el cliente no tenga que usar el scoll para poder verlo

```
 <div id='miContenido'>
      <a name='miLink'>

     <!-- Imagenes y Contenido

      </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Por favor, explica un poco mejor qué es lo que estás intentando. Una función que centre contenido e imágenes en la pantalla, ¿cómo?¿verticalmente, horizontalmente, ambos? Puede haber alternativas como usar CSS, sin necesidad de usar JavaScript (más o menos)

Comment: @Efrain - Esta no es tu primera pregunta, ni la primera vez que se te recomienda que aclares la pregunta siendo más específico. Podrás ver de cumplir lo que se explica en [mcve] en tus publicaciones? Muchas gracias

Comment: Ya  edite la pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Si deseas **centrar una imagen** puedes usar CSS, creo que es lo más apropiado:

```css
IMG.imagencentrada{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<IMG class="imagencentrada" src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded&a" alt="Buna ziua">
</body>
</html>
```

Para **centrar texto** por ejemplo lo realizarías de esta forma:

```css
P.textocentrado {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 6em
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<P class="textocentrado">¡Bienvenidos a todos a nuestro blog internacional para la comunidad de habla hispana! Hemos creado este espacio para poder comunicar y ser más abiertos en como construimos Stack Overflow en español para ustedes. Aquí, trataremos diversos temas que no son adecuados para el sitio meta. Será un lugar donde podremos pensar en voz alta, compartir pensamientos espontáneos, o otras cosas por el estilo. Compartiremos información exclusiva que generalmente no se encontrará en otro lugar. Esperamos que nos sigan apoyando y se unan al nuevo blog de SOes.
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola perdon por no hberme explicado bien ya edite la pregunta ..please

Answer (score 1):

También podrías hacerle `text-align: center;` a miContenido para que todo se centre.

O podrías usar flexbox para jugar con el contenido de la mejor manera y centrar todo.

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

y podría resultar mejor que alguna otra cosa. Pero depende de ti, saludos!

Comment: Hola perdon por no hberme explicado bien ya edite la pregunta ..please